# RxJava filter and emit other items

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android

Its possible to filter and continue emiting itens like below ?

---

My code that calls subscriber 2 times:

```
Observable<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<MockOverview>>> requestEntries =
        this.requestView.request(request)
        .map(HashMap::entrySet)
        .flatMapIterable(entries -> entries);

requestEntries.filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("featured"))
        .map((Func1<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<MockOverview>>, List<MockOverview>>) Map.Entry::getValue)
        .subscribe(mockOverviews -> {
            Log.i("subscrive", "featured");
        });

requestEntries.filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("done"))
        .map((Func1<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<MockOverview>>, List<MockOverview>>) Map.Entry::getValue)
        .subscribe(mockOverviews -> {
            Log.i("subscrive", "featured");
        });
```

---

What i want:

```
 requestEntries.filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("featured"))
        .map((Func1<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<MockOverview>>, List<MockOverview>>) Map.Entry::getValue)
        .subscribe(mockOverviews -> {

        })
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("done"))
        .map((Func1<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<MockOverview>>, List<MockOverview>>) Map.Entry::getValue)
        .subscribe(mockOverviews -> {

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `doOnNext` in the place of the first `subscribe()`

```
 requestEntry.filter(v -> ...)
 .map(v -> ...)
 .doOnNext(v -> ...)
 .filter(v -> ...)
 .map(v -> ...)
 .subscribe(...)
```

or use `publish(Func1)`:

```
 requestEntry.filter(v -> ...)
 .map(v -> ...)
 .publish(o -> {
     o.subscribe(...);
     return o;
 })
 .filter(v -> ...)
 .map(v -> ...)
 .subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

By the looks of things your second version is not equal to your first: the former looks at the `requestEntries` stream twice, filters on *featured* and *done* keys respectively and does its own things with it. Your second version however first filters on *featured* first then does some transformations and side-effects and then filter out the *done*. However, that `Observable<entryset>` is not at all in scope in that second filter lambda.

What you need to do here is use [`publish(<lambda>)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#publish(rx.functions.Func1)) on `requestEntries` and in the lambda do the stuff from your first version, use `onNext` instead of `subscribe`, `merge` the streams and return that combined stream. Then outside of the `publish` you subscribe once (and do nothing in there) or go on and use the result of your stream somewhere else.

```
requestEntries.publish(re -> {
    Observable<...> x = re.filter(...<featured>...).map(...).doOnNext(...Log.i(...));
    Observable<...> y = re.filter(...<done>...).map(...).doOnNext(...Log.i(...));
    return x.mergeWith(y);
})
```